Movie about vampire and agent; at the end, agent and his friend killed king vampire
At the start of this movie, in a bar, vampire blood is given out as drugs.
One man becomes very excited, so the main manager, who is a vampire, comes over and hits him.
One agent and his assistant got a case about a vampire related murder; he meets a main Vampire Association man and asks who did it and he goes for a clue (in the past the agent also had a role as a vampire hunter).
In this film the agent's assistant is killed by a vampire; the agent goes for his body at the morgue, where he lives once again and becomes a vampire. He lost his one hand, so the agent takes him to one shop where all parts of the human body are available for vampires; he finds one hand and fixes it.
On the other side, bad vampires plan to find one type of knife that helps to make a vampire immortal and king of vampires. The agent tries to stop them, but they got it and at the full moon they try to use it, and when they use it, one becomes the vampire king. Agent and his friends try to kill him and finally they kill him, they also kill one girl who helps the vampire become king.
This is Hollywood movie. The title began with a "D" - possibly something with "Dog". This movie was released in 2012 or 2013. I don't remember it perfectly. Many different types of vampires live there in the city.

For now, I've down-voted because I'm really struggling to understand some parts of your question.

May be my English is poor, but this movie released in 2012 approx, and name started with D, (something dog) may be this movie name..

Similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Breed_(2001_film). What language was it in/

No, the breed is diffent for this movie, this release in 2012 or 2013, and I am sure that dog present in this movie, just example delong dog or something, but I can't get name from search..
This is Hollywood movie..

It's Dylan Dog: Dead of Night with Brandon Routh. I think your question is fine, it just needs some proofing (I'll get to it).

@Walt: I tried proofing and stopped because I didn't understand if I was proofing in a way that contradicted the original intent or not. Your answer sounds good, just needs added below!

Thank once again Walt.. Dylan dog: dead of night is this movie.. Now going to watch it online..

Sorry, I just wanted to improve it first. ;)

You're looking for Dylan Dog: Dead of Night from 2011. From Rotten Tomatoes:

DYLAN DOG: DEAD OF NIGHT is a new horror/comedy film based on one of the world's most popular comics (60 million copies worldwide). Brandon Routh stars as Dylan Dog, world famous private investigator specializing in affairs of the undead. His PI business card reads "No Pulse? No Problem." Armed with an edgy wit and carrying an arsenal of silver and wood-tipped bullets, Dylan must track down a dangerous artifact before a war ensues between his werewolf, vampire and zombie clients living undercover in the monster infested backstreets of New Orleans.

Everything you've described is in there. Here's the trailer (where you can see the scene where he gets his zombie assistant a new arm):



